# ERROR Unable to process event: 'java.time.Instant ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent.getInstant()'

Tags: spring-boot, elastic-stack, spring-logback, logstash-logback-encoder

I tried to use `logstash-logback-encoder` with spring boot for sending logs to the ELK. but unfortunately I get this error.

```
|-ERROR in net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender[LOGSTASH] - Unable to process event: 'java.time.Instant ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent.getInstant()' java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.time.Instant ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent.getInstant()'
at java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.time.Instant ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent.getInstant()'
at  at net.logstash.logback.composite.loggingevent.LoggingEventFormattedTimestampJsonProvider.getTimestampAsInstant(LoggingEventFormattedTimestampJsonProvider.java:29)
at  at net.logstash.logback.composite.loggingevent.LoggingEventFormattedTimestampJsonProvider.getTimestampAsInstant(LoggingEventFormattedTimestampJsonProvider.java:25)
at  at net.logstash.logback.composite.AbstractFormattedTimestampJsonProvider.writeTo(AbstractFormattedTimestampJsonProvider.java:164)
at  at net.logstash.logback.composite.JsonProviders.writeTo(JsonProviders.java:78)
at  at net.logstash.logback.composite.AbstractCompositeJsonFormatter.writeEventToGenerator(AbstractCompositeJsonFormatter.java:290)
at  at net.logstash.logback.composite.AbstractCompositeJsonFormatter$JsonFormatter.writeEvent(AbstractCompositeJsonFormatter.java:190)
at  at net.logstash.logback.composite.AbstractCompositeJsonFormatter.writeEvent(AbstractCompositeJsonFormatter.java:156)
at  at net.logstash.logback.encoder.CompositeJsonEncoder.encode(CompositeJsonEncoder.java:106)
at  at net.logstash.logback.encoder.CompositeJsonEncoder.encode(CompositeJsonEncoder.java:80)
at  at net.logstash.logback.encoder.CompositeJsonEncoder.encode(CompositeJsonEncoder.java:36)
at  at net.logstash.logback.appender.AbstractLogstashTcpSocketAppender$TcpSendingEventHandler.encode(AbstractLogstashTcpSocketAppender.java:654)
at  at net.logstash.logback.appender.AbstractLogstashTcpSocketAppender$TcpSendingEventHandler.writeEvent(AbstractLogstashTcpSocketAppender.java:616)
at  at net.logstash.logback.appender.AbstractLogstashTcpSocketAppender$TcpSendingEventHandler.onEvent(AbstractLogstashTcpSocketAppender.java:580)
at  at net.logstash.logback.appender.AbstractLogstashTcpSocketAppender$TcpSendingEventHandler.onEvent(AbstractLogstashTcpSocketAppender.java:291)
at  at net.logstash.logback.appender.AsyncDisruptorAppender$EventClearingEventHandler.onEvent(AsyncDisruptorAppender.java:363)
at  at net.logstash.logback.appender.AsyncDisruptorAppender$EventClearingEventHandler.onEvent(AsyncDisruptorAppender.java:350)
at  at net.logstash.logback.encoder.com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.processEvents(BatchEventProcessor.java:168)
```

The version of `logstash-logback-encoder` is `7.4`.

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
   <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
   <version>7.4</version>
</dependency>
```

The `logback-spring.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<included>

    <property resource="application.properties"/>

    <appender name="LOGSTASH" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
        <destination>143.198.201.49:5000</destination>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>DEBUG</level>
        </filter>
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">

            <providers>
                <timestamp>
                    <timeZone>UTC</timeZone>
                </timestamp>
                <mdc/>
                <context/>
                <logLevel/>
                <loggerName/>
                <pattern>
                    <pattern>
                        {
                        "test": "test-value",
                        "app": "${spring.application.name}"
                        }
                    </pattern>
                </pattern>
                <threadName/>
                <message/>
                <logstashMarkers/>
                <stackTrace/>
            </providers>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="LOGSTASH"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
</included>
```

can I have a solution please.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

logstash-logback-encoder >= 7.4 requires logback >= 1.3

Therefore, you have two options to solve your problem:

A. Continue using logstash-logback-encoder >= 7.4, and upgrade logback >= 1.3

OR

B. Downgrade logstash-logback-encoder to 7.3 (which supports logback 1.2), and continue using logback 1.2.

Comment: Great! That was the problem.

Comment: For users of SpringBoot 2.7...  SB 2.7 uses logback 1.2 and based on experiments, it seems like you should stick with the 7.3 logstash-logback-encoder (Option B).  SB 2.7 + encoder 7.4 + logback 1.3 + slf4j 1.x gave me build errors.  Hold off on Option A until SpringBoot 3.x.  Not the authority on this, but might save you some headaches

Comment: Uh why is that not a major release...

Comment: @EduardoBueno Yeah, it should definitely be treated as a breaking change and marked with a major version. I lost half a day analyzing this...

Answer (score 0):

For those who have this issue with the latest SB 2.7 version, it worked for me by adding the latest version of 'slf4j-api'

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
```